# excel4node lib to autosize excel cell in order to fit longer text

Tags: node.js, excel, excel4node

Using excel4node lib in order to generate excel docs out of some web tables, is there a possibility to autosize cell when the text is too long to fit it in one cell and to make the width of the cell bigger?

In [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node) they have this 2 functions:

```
ws.column(3).setWidth(50);
ws.row(1).setHeight(20);
```

But that won't fit the text inside, will just make the cell bigger. Will show example:

[image]

and my desired output:

[image]

Code for that comment cell:

```
reducedReport.forEach((element, index) => {
        ws.cell(index + 2, 1).string(element["projectName"]);
        ws.cell(index + 2, 2).string(element["workerName"]);
        ws.cell(index + 2, 3).string(element["comment"]);
        ws.column(3).setWidth(30);
        ws.row(15).setHeight(40);
        ws.cell(index + 2, 4).string(moment(element["date"] * 1000).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
        console.log(element["comment"]);
    });
```

It's about comment column.

Answer (score 0):

you can add alignment settings for cell setting :

```
alignment: { 
    shrinkToFit: true, 
    wrapText: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not implemented yet, [as exposed in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/natergj/excel4node/issues/95). In that issue, [the author is pointing to an approximation approach used by PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/257c3eca5870dbfaf89eb344fb31c07dfbb74456/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/Font.php#L315), to dynamically set the column's width considering the font and the content's length.